# how to exclude API routes witch contain certain specific method in express jwt

Tags: node.js, api, express, jwt, express-jwt

```
app.use(`${api}/products`, productsRoutes);
app.use(`${api}/users`, usersRoutes);
```

i have routes i want that the api with GET method in products should be excluded in express jwt?

```
require("dotenv").config();
const api = process.env.API_URL
const jwt = require('express-jwt')
function authjwt() {
const secret = process.env.secret;

    return jwt({ secret, algorithms: ['HS256'] }).unless({path: 
    
    ['/api/v1/  products',
     
    
    '/api/v1/  login',
    
    ]}));
    module.exports = authjwt
```